Prefactor $2\pi i$ for Tate-Hodge structure
A rather basic question. What was the original reason to consider the underlying $\mathbb{Z}$-module of the - as canonical object regarded - Tate-Hodge structure $\mathbb{Z}(1)$ to be given as $2 \pi i \mathbb{Z} (\subset \mathbb{C}$) endowed with this notorious factor $2 \pi i$.
Looks like a (historically arising) normalization factor, but with respect to what/ which form (...which presumably should be expressed in terms of certain integrals over loops).
Clearly, as Hodge structure is an additional datum not extractible only from the underlying $\mathbb{Z}$- module structure, it is choiceless to define those Hodge structures $H$ with one dimensional $H \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{C}$ to have a $r \cdot \mathbb{Z}, r \in \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ as underlying $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure, but which original condition precisely motivated to take the factor $2 \pi i$ for THS $\mathbb{Z}(1)$?
Does anybody know reason or a source adressing this rather natural question ( for which suprisingly searching on the web I found no source discussing this issue even though this question may permanently pop up  after becoming acquainted with this arguably first example for a pure Hodge structure which one encouters as a student). As remarked it seems that this should presumable come from certain normalization condition for Hodge structure of deRham cohomology groups of compact complex manifolds (one may feel free to focus to $X=\mathbb{PC}^n$ only). But which one? Does somebody where this could be found elaborated?

see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2285381/87355

You are right that it is in some sense  a matter of convention, but I claim it's a natural one.
Perhaps the easiest example to explain is $H=H_1(X)$, where $X=\mathbb{C}^*$. By Deligne, this carries a(n a priori mixed) Hodge structure, which is one dimensional and pure of weight $-2$, and therefore isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}(1)$.  In fact, let's take this as the definition. Then
the natural generator of $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is the unit  circle $\gamma$ oriented counterclockwise. The natural generator of $H^{-1.-1}$ is dual to $dz/z$. The change of basis matrix is just $\int_\gamma dz/z=2\pi i$.

probably I see. So if I understand it correctly then the historical motivation for this factor $2 \pi i$ comes from the desire to describe $H_1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ explicitly as dual space of "integral" deRham classes via explicit isomorphism $V \cong V^*$ (ie explicit identification of a space with it's dual) via pairing/bilinear form induced by usual integration, right?

But if that's the whole reason behind multiplying with this factor, one could ask provocatively why we should modify $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ by multiplying with this factor $2 \pi i$ and not conversely instead modifying all integer deRham forms by multiplying them by factor $1/2 \pi i$? Ie why modifying $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ instead of modifying integer deRham forms is "more natural"?

(1) I'm not a historian, I imagine that $\mathbb{P}^1$ was the first example understood along these lines. But it is closely related to the example I just gave. (2) Sure, the $2\pi i$ has to go somewhere...
